# Asian fonts aren't displaying in Teeworlds

Tags: pc, linux, teeworlds

In Teeworlds on Linux, Korean/Chinese/Japanese fonts just display as a bunch of []s. This is true both in-game and in the settings:

[image: Example of square blocks instead of characters]

This is true whether I install from my package repository, the Teeworlds [Downloads](https://teeworlds.com/?page=downloads) page, or from [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.teeworlds.Teeworlds).

Note: It was NOT the case when I downloaded the modded DDNET client. Korean worked fine there.

This happened both on Arch Linux KDE, as well as KUbuntu 20.04

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

So I asked on their [Github](https://github.com/teeworlds/teeworlds/issues/2857) and it seems like this is fixed, but not yet in the latest release. If you see this issue on a version **later** than 0.7.5, you're likely encountering a different problem.